# Progressive Web Apps add to Home Screen functionality for different states

Tags: angularjs, progressive-web-apps

Anyone has any idea how we can work with different urls in PWA. As of now I go to any url on the site and add that page to home screen it takes me to the home state.
I wanted to preserve the current state.
Please let me know if anyone has any information about it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code and error logs (if there is any)?

Answer (score 0):

It should load the standalone app on the URL specified in the `start_url` in the Web App Manifest.

Perhaps by storing some more information in Storage or IndexedDB you can maintain the user's state, however when opening an app (including native apps) it is ordinary that the user journey starts from an initial screen rather than continuing from where they left off.

Answer (score 0):

Progressive Web App Start page would be using `start_url` in manifest.json. I just try Aliexpress.com I try to change to another page then add to home screen. After click icon from desktop is direct to start_url

Comment: if it has a start url and u go to some other page and add to homescreen then also it would add the home page to the homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers I can think of (I haven't tried though)

1. Generate the meta tag for manifest dynamically on your webpage (notice the *?category=111*, or any variable to identify `<link rel="manifest" href="https://suraurgeet.com/manifest.json?category=111">`
2. When manifest.json is requested from server, return a dynamically
   generated json. Say you are on php: along with other other json_parse values, `echo "start_url: ".$someUrlofChoiceBasedonCategory111;`

Beyond whether it is implementable, to be honest, I am afraid of multiple shortcuts on user screen, spoiling the experience?
Or you never know a convenience for repetitive use with multiple PWA shortcuts: say "Buy  on flpkrt" or " Dashboard"

**UPDATE** I just checked, You do get a referer to GET request of manifest.json. You can for sure use it to fetch dynamic manifest.json. So you can possibly skip the first step I mentioned.